Orientability of $6$-manifold and vanishing of every Euler class
Let $M$ be a connected, closed, smooth $6$-manifold such that the Euler class of every orientable vector bundle over $M$ vanishes. What can be said about the orientability of $M$?

Out of interest, what was your motivation for this question?

Say a closed manifold $M$ has property $V$ if every orientable vector bundle on $M$ has vanishing Euler class.
The first thing to note is that every closed, orientable, even-dimensional manifold admits an orientable vector bundle with non-zero Euler class. To see this, suppose $\dim M = 2n$ and let $f : M \to S^{2n}$ be a degree one map. Consider the bundle $E := f^*TS^{2n}$. Since $TS^{2n}$ is orientable, so too is $E$. Moreover, $e(E) = e(f^*TS^{2n}) = f^*e(TS^{2n}) \neq 0$ as $e(TS^{2n}) \neq 0$ and $f^* : H^{2n}(S^{2n}; \mathbb{Z}) \to H^{2n}(M; \mathbb{Z})$ is an isomorphism.
Therefore, if a $6$-manifold $M$ has property $V$, then $M$ is non-orientable. Does such a manifold exist though?
Example: Let $M$ be the total space of the non-orientable (linear) $S^5$-bundle over $S^1$; equivalently, the mapping torus of a reflection. It is a closed non-orientable $6$-manifold with cohomology groups
$$\begin{array}{c|ccccccc} 
i & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ \hline
H^i(M; \mathbb{Z}) & \mathbb{Z} & \mathbb{Z} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \mathbb{Z}_2 \\ 
H^i(M; \mathbb{Z}_2) & \mathbb{Z}_2 & \mathbb{Z}_2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \mathbb{Z}_2 & \mathbb{Z}_2 
\end{array}$$
Let $E \to M$ be an orientable vector bundle of rank $r > 0$. If $r \neq 1, 6$, then $e(E) = 0$ as $H^r(M; \mathbb{Z}) = 0$, while if $r = 1$, the bundle $E$ is trivial, so $e(E) = 0$. That leaves only $r = 6$.
The short exact sequence $0 \to \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{\times 2} \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_2 \to 0$ induces a long exact sequence in cohomology which shows that the reduction mod $2$ map $H^6(M;\mathbb{Z}) \to H^6(M; \mathbb{Z})$ is an isomorphism. Under this map $e(E) \mapsto w_6(E)$, so $e(E)$ vanishes if and only if $w_6(E)$ does. Since $E$ is orientable and $r = 6$, the total Stiefel-Whitney class of $E$ takes the form $w(E) = 1 + w_5(E) + w_6(E)$. However, it follows from the Wu formula that the first $i > 0$ for which $w_i(E) \neq 0$ is a power of $2$, so we have $w_5(E) = 0$ and $w_6(E) = 0$. Therefore $e(E) = 0$, so $M$ has property $V$.

One can generalise the above beyond dimension $6$:

If $M$ is an even-dimensional manifold with property $V$, then $M$ is non-orientable.
For every $d$ which is not a power of $2$, the non-trivial $S^{d-1}$-bundle over $S^1$ is a non-orientable $d$-manifold with property $V$.

When $d$ is a power of $2$, the non-trivial $S^{d-1}$-bundle over $S^1$ need not have property $V$.
Example: When $d = 2$, the manifold of interest is the non-orientable $S^1$-bundle over $S^1$, i.e. the Klein bottle. Since $H^2(M; \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$, there is an orientable rank $2$ bundle $E \to M$ with $e(E) \neq 0$. Such a bundle can be constructed as follows. Since $w_1(M) \neq 0$, there is $\alpha \in H^1(M; \mathbb{Z}_2)$ with $w_1(M)\cup\alpha \neq 0$ by Poincaré duality. Let $L$ be a real line bundle with $w_1(L) = \alpha$. Then $E := L\oplus L$ has Stiefel-Whitney classes $w_1(E) = 0$ and $w_2(E) = w_1(L)^2 = \alpha^2 = \operatorname{Sq}^1(\alpha) = \nu_1\cup\alpha = w_1(M)\cup\alpha \neq 0$. As before, the mod $2$ reduction map $H^2(M; \mathbb{Z}) \to H^2(M; \mathbb{Z}_2)$ is an isomorphism which sends $e(E)$ to $w_2(E)$, so $e(E) \neq 0$. Therefore $M$ does not have property $V$.
In fact, if $d \in \{2, 4, 8\}$, then is no $d$-dimensional manifold with property $V$. To see this, let $M$ be a closed $d$-dimensional manifold and choose a map $f: M \to S^d$ with $\mathbb{Z}_2$-degree one. By Walschap - The Euler class a cohomology generator, there is an orientable rank $d$ vector bundle $E \to S^d$ with $e(E) \neq 0$ (in fact, a generator of $H^d(S^d; \mathbb{Z})$). Then $f^*E \to M$ is an orientable rank $d$ vector bundle, and as before, one can show that $e(f^*E) \neq 0$.
Naturally, one could also consider odd $d$. There are the non-orientable examples from the second dot point, but it is no longer the case that a manifold with property $V$ must be non-orientable. For example, every odd-dimensional integral homology sphere $M$ has property $V$. To see this, note that $e(E) = 0$ if $\operatorname{rank}(E) \neq d$. If $\operatorname{rank}(E) = d$, then the Euler class $e(E)$ is $2$-torsion since $d$ is odd, but $H^d(M; \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ is torsion-free, so $e(E) = 0$.
